# cocoa lost animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I got lots of transform animations in my application. Everything worked fine, but after a while turns off the animation. Any. Even keyboard appearance. I test it on the iphone simulator.

What may cause that?

Comment: You need to clarify your question and add more details. Otherwise no one will be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that same problem some time ago. I can't really explain why this happens but the way to fix it is to guarantee that all animations are performed in the main thread. So if you are running some code in a background thread make sure you call the animation like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodThatPerformsTheAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Good luck!